# Implementing a "Minimum Heuristic" in backtracking algorithm to solve puzzles in Python

Tags: python, recursion

I've recently gotten into solving puzzles and recursion/backtracking.
Im trying to solve the 6x6 Skyscraper puzzle which consists of filling in a 6x6 board based on specific clues given to us.
I've done as much constraint programming as i could, but in order to solve certain puzzles i have to resort to brute forcing the end.

What a row in my board looks like exiting the constraint functions is something like this:

`board = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 6, [1, 2, 3, 5, 6], [1, 2, 4, 5], [1, 3], [2, 3, 4, 5]]`
where the sublists are the different possibilities for that specific cell. (so the cell can be either 1 2 3 4 or 5 in the first sublist).

I've managed to implement a backtracking brute force method that works but **would like to try to have a minimum heuristic such as a priority is given to the cells with the smallest amount of possibilities**.
Here's what I have so far:

```
def search(searchBoard, clues):
    findLeast = full(searchBoard)
    if not findLeast:
        return True
    else:
        row , col = findLeast
    val = searchBoard[row][col]
    for i in searchBoard[row][col]:
        if is_valid(searchBoard, clues, 6, i, (row, col)):
            searchBoard[row][col] = i
            if search(searchBoard, clues):
                return True
            searchBoard[row][col] = val
    return False

def full(puzzle):
    try:
        min = 0
        for i in range(len(puzzle)):
            for j in range(1 ,len(puzzle)):
                if isinstance(puzzle[i][j] , list):
                    if len(puzzle[i][j-1]) < len(puzzle[i][j]):
                        min = len(puzzle[i][j-1])
                        pos = (i , j-1)
        return pos
    except TypeError:
        return None
```

And is_valid checks if the element can be inserted into a specific cell or not.

(edited some syntax mistakes in my code)